# How to locate 'symbols' by means of grid cells in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, vector-grid

I am new to Mapinfo and GIS in general, but I have a new job in a company that works with maps and GPS and now I am being trained.  My question, and I have looked a lot and I couldn't find anything, is I want to make an object be connected with a grid cell.  For example I have a symbol on a map and I have also have a grid (square cells from Gridmaker) I want to know which symbol intersects with which grid cell.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange @sarah. Please take the time to write your posts with proper punctuation and capitalization. After all, you want others to donate their time to help you, so please put some effort into formulating your questions.

Comment: [Punctuation saves lives](http://exactlywrite.blogspot.com/2010/03/punctuation-saves-lives.html)

Comment: Add to what @underdark said, Detail your question as much as you can.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this:

Open the MapBasic Window and paste the following:

```
SELECT * FROM  [GRID_TABLE_NAME] , [Symbol_TABLE_NAME] WHERE  [GRID_TABLE_NAME].OBJ INTERSECTS [Symbol_TABLE_NAME].obj INTO ObjsIntersect
BROWSE * FROM ObjsIntersect
```

I'm, doing this from memory, so the syntax may be:

```
SELECT * FROM  [GRID_TABLE_NAME] , [Symbol_TABLE_NAME] WHERE  [GRID_TABLE_NAME].OBJ INTERSECTS [Symbol_TABLE_NAME].obj INTO ObjsIntersect
BROWSE * FROM TABLE ObjsIntersect
```

You will obviously have to change the names of the tables as well.

There are other ways to frame this query, but for the sake of answering the question, this is probably the easiest....

Hope it helps.